# Strange situation, Visual Studio debugging ran through action to view but nothing returned to browser

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have encountered a very strange problem.
Basically, there is a `Delete ActionLink`. Once clicked, the code checks the condition, checks true/false, stays on current page or goes to `Delete view`.

I have posted the solution for this scenario and got some very helpful replies. I worked on it and took it to a situation where I was about to succeed.

Anyway, here are the codes

Index View: AJAX calls the `Delete action`, returns JSON or EmptyResult. If EmptyResult, then it is a failure as the original ActionLink has been disabled, AJAX will call the `error` function, which calls another `action "Delete2"`.

```
<td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CustomerId }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "mergo-actionlink" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CustomerId }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "mergo-actionlink" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CustomerId }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "mergo-actionlink-delete", data_value = item.CustomerId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.mergo-actionlink-delete').click(
function () {
    var clickedId = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Customers")',
        data: { id: clickedId},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.message);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("EmptyResult returns.");
            debugger;
            $.post('@Url.Action("Delete2", "Customers")', { id: clickedId });
        },
        async: false
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Controllers:

```
public ActionResult Delete(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    if (customer.Orders.ToList().Count() != 0)
    {
        return Json(new { message = "This customer has order(s) attached." }, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}

public ActionResult Delete2(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

Delete2.cshtml

```
@model MergoMVC.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Customer</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Password)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

And I do have `Delete.cshtml` and `Delete2.cshtml` views for the actions. The symptom is - from debugging, Visual Studio went into `Delete2` action, returned the "customer" to `Delete2.cshtml` view, executed it from head to toe. But the browser stayed still on index page. I think something is wrong with the `return false;` in the AJAX. I'm new to this, so I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error: function () {
            alert("EmptyResult returns.");
            debugger;
            $.post('@Url.Action("Delete2", "Customers")', { id: clickedId });
        },
```

Result of a post does not refresh your page, so quick fix is to genrate an anchor with URL to controller action add id parameter and click on it or change window location with controller/action/clicked id.

```
error: function () {
                alert("EmptyResult returns.");
                debugger;
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                // something like, not sure :)
                var hrefUri = '@Html.ActionLink("Delete2", "Customers"'); 
                a.href = hrefUri + "/" + clickedId;
                a.click();
}
```

You used page controller as rest api controller, not a bad thing at all but do not mix thing around because maybe someone may work on your code. Usually posting stuff via ajax you expect a JSON result, in a ajax post/get request if you return a view + model you need to update somehow the page.

Answer (score 1):

@SilentTremor Thank you so much sir. You helped me to solve the problem. The working function is (ignore all the comments):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.mergo-actionlink-delete').click(
function () {
    var clickedId = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Customers")',
        data: { id: clickedId },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.message);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("EmptyResult returns.");
            debugger;
            //var a = document.createElement('a');
            @*var hrefUri = '@Html.ActionLink("Delete2", "Customers")';*@
            @*var href = '@Html.ActionLink("Delete2", "Customers")/' + clickedId;*@
            window.location.href = @*'@Html.ActionLink("Delete2", "Customers")/' + clickedId;*@
                '@Url.Action("Delete2", "Customers")/' + clickedId;
            //a.click();
        },
        async: false
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

When I executed your code, I got a `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).` error. The < is from the anchor. Could you please kindly clarify this part? - `You used page controller as rest api controller, not a bad thing at all but do not mix thing around because maybe someone may work on your code.` Is it something about `post`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: well i was incorrect :) @Html.ActionLink does create an anchor like <a href=... and on href atribute <> tags were present, sorry about that, anyhow you nail'd it. I'm glad you got the point, now let clarify post problem, you did a post to a page controller action via ajax witch return view, as ajax call with post you expect a response (restful controler) in json format, with that json you could have ssucces or error message. And if you expect row html from you controller, return partial view without layout or another global stuff, just the html and $(".wrapper").html(data_from_delete2_post)